# I cannot run multiple test files with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have just started with Jest today.  I have a simple test file in my `__tests__` directory.  Here is the current test file:

```
describe('ChangeCalendarView', function() {
    it('true', function() {
        expect(3).toBe(3);
    })
});
```

This runs with no issue.  When I add another file, with the same exact code, other than the description:

```
describe('ChangeTimePeriod', function() {
    it('true', function() {
        expect(3).toBe(3);
    })
});
```

Then I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/node-worker-pool/Worker.js:93
    throw new Error('Received unexpected data from child process: ' + data);
          ^
Error: Received unexpected data from child process: {
  "error": "Error: ENOENT, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest-cli/.haste_cache/cache-react-calendar-component'\n\n"
}
  at Worker._onStdout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/node-worker-pool/Worker.js:93:11)
```

Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: Hmm,  there must be something else going on here, either in your environment  or around those test blocks. Does this happen when you add _any_ new test file, or just that specific one?

Comment: Any file I add makes the same thing happen. But if I only leave one file it will always run

Comment: What are the file names of the tests? I wonder if it is a parking issue with jest. Also, It may seem silly, but I'd also try blowing away node_modules and running npm install again.

Comment: The names are `ChangeCalendarView-test.js` and `ChangeTimePeriod-test.js`.  I `rm`'ed my `node_modules` and pulled down everything fresh, but still had the same problems.

Comment: I've the similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to specify exact multiple files to run tests on, just separate files' names with space.

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed this issue by using babel-jest. Here my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.1.3",
    "dev": "^0.1.3",
    "flux": "^2.0.3",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "immutable": "^3.7.4",
    "install": "^0.1.8",
    "lodash": "^3.10.0",
    "node-simple-static-server": "^1.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.23.7",
    "react-router": "^0.13.3",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.18.0",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.0-beta.2",
    "stackup": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^5.3.0",
    "babelify": "^6.1.2",
    "browser-sync": "latest",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.0",
    "del": "~0.1.3",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~1.0.1",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.6",
    "gulp-cache": "~0.2.4",
    "gulp-imagemin": "latest",
    "gulp-jshint": "~1.8.5",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.7.0",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "~0.7.1",
    "gulp-size": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-strip-debug": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-stylus": "~2.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-useref": "~0.4.4",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-webserver": "latest",
    "jest-cli": "*",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.6.2",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-tools": "latest",
    "reactify": "latest",
    "strip-debug": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "watchify": "~2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "../node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "es6",
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "es6"
    ],
    "rootDir": "./app",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "react",
      "events",
      "lodash"
    ]
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim",
      [
        "reactify",
        {
          "es6": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$"
  }
}
```

[image: screen result]

Answer (score 4):

The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files. By default it looks for .js and .jsx files inside of **tests** folders, as well as any files with a suffix of .test or .spec (e.g. Component.test.js or Component.spec.js). It will also find files called test.js or spec.js. 
 So name your test file  with suffix .test .Like  ***pagination.test.js* .**